# Very simple SQL query on varchar fields with sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I created a table with this schema using sqlite3:

```
CREATE TABLE monitored_files (file_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,file_name VARCHAR(32767),original_relative_dir_path VARCHAR(32767),backupped_relative_dir_path VARCHAR(32767),directory_id INTEGER);
```

now, I would like to get all the records where original_relative_dir_path is exactly equal to '.', without 's. What I did is this:

```
select * from monitored_files where original_relative_dir_path='.';
```

The result is no records even if in the table I have just this record:

```
1|'P9040479.JPG'|'.'|'.'|1
```

I read on the web and I see no mistakes in my syntax... I also tried using LIKE '.', but still no results. I'm not an expert of SQL so maybe you can see something wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are not storing the single quotes around the values in the database?

Comment: I suppose you're right! I created the insert query using Qt, and it seems that it inserts the single quotes where it should not... Then the problem is more related to Qt than to sqlite. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no problem with the statement.
I created the table that you described.
Did an INSERT with the same values that you provided.
And did the query, and also queried without a where clause.
No problems encountered, so I suspect that when you execute your selection, you may not be connected to the correct database.